# How to find the $S_\kappa$ elements in the product $ \sum_{\kappa=1}^{K} S_\kappa Q_\kappa(r, \theta,\phi) = 1$?

Tags: linear-algebra

So I have one K-dimensional complex column vector $\textbf{S}$ and a set of K complex functions $Q_\kappa(r,\theta,\phi) \forall \kappa \in \{1,\dots,K\}$ defined in spherical coordinates.

I know all the K functions and the following equality holds:

$$ \sum_{\kappa=1}^{K} S_\kappa Q_\kappa(r, \theta,\phi) = 1$$

Is there a way to find the $S_\kappa$ elements of vector $\mathbf{S}$? Perhaps multiples ways? Or an algorithm to systematically find solutions?

P.S. Sorry about the tags, but I have no idea what tags I should put in this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select random $(r,\theta,\phi)$ triples and note down corresponding $\mathbf Q$ vectors. When you have enough $Q$ points that they define a $(K-1)$-dimensional hyperplane, calculate its equation and normalize so the constant term is $1$. The coefficients of the $Q_\kappa$s are then your desired $\mathbf S$.

This only works if $\mathbf S$ is unique. If there are several possible $\mathbf S$s, then you can't ever be sure that they all *are* possible solutions, without knowing something about how the $Q$ function work. It might me that there's a single $(r,\theta,\phi)$ that will reject one of them, but you just haven't tried it yet.

Comment: When will I know if my triples define a K-1 dimensional hyperplane?

Comment: @urquiza: You need at least $K$ points. Once you have that, assume they define a hyperplane and try to determine its equation (for example by the method of undetermined coefficients). If there's no unique solution for the coefficients, discard one of the $\mathbf Q$s and try again.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood the method for solving this. What is that "undetermined coefficients" method? I'm pretty sure this is what I'm looking for, and the **S** vector is unique, but I'm not sure of how do I calculate the equation of a plane in this case, when the "x's" are functions.

Comment: @urquiza: The equation of the plane is $S_1Q_1+S_2Q_2+\cdots +S_KQ_K=1$. Each time you insert a set of $Q$ values into that, you get an equation where you can choose to view the $S$s as unknowns. Once you have $K$ such equations, you can solve the system of $K$ equations with $K$ unknowns using standard linear algebra techniques (suchs as Gaussian elimination).